# How to add a convert a normal string value into a dollar value in react when user is typing

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, currency

How to change a string value to dollars when user is typing.
Ex:- if the user type something like 5995.
How can I convert this to $59.95 when the user is typing.

And also when the user is saving the value how can I convert it back to a string value and pass it to the back-end.

```
export const getCurrency = (value) => "$" + (value/100).toFixed(2);

export function convertCurrencyToString(value) {
    const removeDollar = value.replace("$", "");
    return removeDollar * 100
}
```

I tried on using these methods  to convert it to string and then again convert them to dollars. But this is ok if the value is not changing. But when the value is changing I am getting un-expected errors from the front-end.

as I cant edit the values next to the (.) and etc.

Any suggetions how to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the dollar sign and the decimal dots on every change of the input field and then re-apply the pattern you want.

See the example below. It is very simple just to show you how it can be done. It lacks the validation of non numeric characters.

```js
const App = (props) => {
  var [count, setCount] = React.useState('')

  const change = val => {
    setCount('$' + (val.replace('$', '').replaceAll('.', '') / 100).toFixed(2))
  }
  
  return ( 
    <input value={count} onChange={e => change(e.target.value)} />
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: ok, but will this be added when the user is typing? Or will this be added after the user is finished typing?

Comment: please click **run code snippet** to check it live :)